# Store token in cookie with Django Rest Framework TokenAuthentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, setcookie

I'm preparing the authentication (with TokenAuthentication) process of my application and for security purposes, I'd like to store the token into a HttpOnly cookie.

For that I've created my own view to get the token.
In fact, I'm overriding the default `rest_framework.authtoken.views.ObtainAuthToken` like below :

```py
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.response import Response


class ObtainCookieAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
    """
    Override default ObtainAuthToken view from rest_framework to set the token into a
    HttpOnly cookie.
    The 'secure' option will depend on the settings.DEBUG value.
    """
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        response = Response({
            'user': "user is %s" % user.full_name,
            'other': "some other info here"
        })
        response.set_cookie(
            "auth-token",
            token,
            httponly=True,
            secure=settings.DEBUG,
        )
        return response
```

In my URLs :

```py
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from .base.authentication.obtain_cookie_auth_token import ObtainCookieAuthToken


urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('api/api-token-auth/', ObtainCookieAuthToken.as_view()),
    # ...
]
```

After that in a custom class that will override default `rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication` I will check for that cookie to retrieve the token from it.

**The problem is that the cookie isn't created while my `ObtainCookieAuthToken` is effectively called.
Am I missing something ? I do not understand why the cookie isn't created... I thought `set_cookie` for the `response` would do the trick.**

By the way here is how I call this APi endpoint, my `login()` method from my Vuejs frontend :

```js
login () {
  this.axios
    .post('api-token-auth/', {
      username: this.form.username || this.lastLoggedInUser.username,
      password: this.form.password
    })
    .then(response => {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("error : ", error)
    })
},
```

Strange thing is that it seems to be present in the response headers :

[image]

While in other similar posts the questions were 'how to', here it is 'why it does not work ?'

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe it has some concerns with CORS ? Because when developping I'm running my Django backend on port `8000` and my Vuejs frontend is running on the port `8080` ?

Comment: This will be the case only when developping (to have the hot reload). On production, Django will serve the Vue app as static files.